# Flutter how to get all the days of the week as string

Tags: flutter, dart

AS stated in the title: Is there an easy way to get all the days of the week as List of string?

for current Week
OutPut: ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as an option:

```
var now = DateTime.now();
var startFrom = now.subtract(Duration(days: now.weekday));
var list = List.generate(7, (i) => '${startFrom.add(Duration(days: i)).day}');
print('$list');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
var now = DateTime.now();
var startDate= now.subtract(Duration(days: now.weekday));
var listDate = List.generate(7, (i) => '${startDate.add(Duration(days: i)).day}');
print('$listDate ');
```

or can use Flutter package
[weekdays](https://pub.dev/packages/weekdays)